# How to install CakePHP in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apache2, php, lamp, phpmyadmin

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 for and LAMP configuration run on it. In some projects of CakePHP, it didn't show some content or didn't redirect the page according to need of code. I think it is problem due to CakePHP is not installed on my system.

I actually don't know how to install CakePHP or is it really need to install CakePHP after installing LAMP environment and phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steps are almost same but in Windows we did that using GUI or in Windows Explorer and in Ubuntu we'll do it through terminal or you can say using commands.

**Step 1**:  Open the command prompt (terminal) and type the following command

```
cd /var/www/html
```

**Step 2**: Type the below command to download the cakephp.

```
$ sudo wget https://codeload.github.com/cakephp/cakephp/legacy.zip/2.5.2
```

where 2.5.2 is the latest stable version of CakePHP.

**Step 3**: Use the following command to unzip the downloaded zip file.

```
$ sudo unzip 2.5.2
```

**Step 4**:  Rename extracted folder.

```
$ mv cakephp-cakephp-736e999/ cake
```

where cakephp-cakephp-736e999 is the name of extracted folder.

To run CakePHP on browser use this path localhost/cake.

**Step 5**: Go to cake folder.

```
$ cd cake
```

And change permissions to app/tmp folder.

```
$ sudo chown -R root:www-data app/tmp
$ sudo chmod -R 775 app/tmp
```

**Step 6**: To make script writable perform these steps:

```
$ apache2ctl -M
```

If you see mod_rewrite or rewrite_module in the list shown then script is writable. If not then to enable it type this command:

```
$ a2enmod rewrite
```

**Step 7**: Type:-

```
  cd /etc/apache2 
$ sudo nano  apache2.conf
```

Set these lines in the file:

```
    <Directory /var/www>
       Option Indexes FollowSymlinks
       AllowOverride All
       Required all granted
    </Directory>
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, then press <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file.

Restart apache:

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

**Step 8**: Now go to app/Config and:

```
$ cd /var/www/html/cake/app/Config
$ sudo mv database.php.default default.php
```

Refresh localhost/cake page. Now database file is detected but still we have to create a database as it will show could not connect to database.

**Step 9**: Open localhost/phpmyadmin on browser. Login using your username and password and create a database named as cake. After this edit database.php file.

```
$ sudo nano database.php
```

Set host as localhost, username is your phpmyadmin username, password is your phpmyadmin password and database name.

Refresh localhost/cake page. Now database is detected.

**Step 10**: To remove the salt and seed error shown on top of the localhost/cake page we have to edit core.php file.

```
$ sudo nano core.php
```

Find this section and replace both the strings with any random strings or you can use these strings also.

```
/* A random string used in security hashing methods. */

 Configure::write('Security.salt','fvjhdj8fvn85grg73fbrvfn9fjFGfnhvt758nADG');

/* A random numeric string (digits only) used to encrypt/decrypt strings. */

Configure::write('Security.cipherSeed', '55857485748594575784348784787475');
```

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, press <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save file.
Refresh localhost/cake page. And its done.